# htaccess for dynamic username

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Hi i'm using this code for my subdirectories redirect for usernames

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ profile.php?username=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

I have this problem that is user enter domain.com/username/ it will have problems, it only works if they enter domain.com/username

Any solutions to this??

Also, example if i have a real directory call /images/, when they enter domain.com/images. there will be an error regarding some looping problem. what is the way to solve this issue?

Comment: try `RewriteRule ^/(.*)/?*$ profile.php?username=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}` and better test if user enter `domain.com/username//` or even `domain.com/username///`

Comment: that doesnt work. I wonder is there anything to trim $1 if it has a extra / at the back?

Comment: sia - it `/?` supposedly to match 0 or 1, hopefully

Answer (score 0):

It's better to make your rewrites require the trailing slash.

then you can redirect non-slash ended urls to slash ended one,

using something like this :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: can't do, i need to remove the / if not is will redirect to profile.php?username=username/ which is invalid

Comment: Never mind, you can reverse my answer to redirect from slash ended urls to other one.

Comment: i'm not very clear of what you mean? can you show me an example from your code. please. my condition is if domain.com/username and domain.com/username/ works.

Comment: Have you tried this rule : `RewriteRule ^(.*)?/?*$ profile.php?username=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}`, if it's not working, try to add this line `RewriteRule ^(.+)/$  /$1 [R=301,L]` before this rule `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ profile.php?username=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}`

Comment: i tried the second way, it works but there are two problems, firstly, when i goto www.domain.com it will automatically convert to www.domain.com/profile.php?username= which return an error user. next, my css and javascript doesnt load, they are in physical folders.